# Struct that only accepts boolean values

Tags: racket

How would I make a struct that only takes a value if it's a boolean

```
(struct mystruct [val]  //only take val if it's a boolean )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least 3 ways:

1. Define the struct with a contract, using [`define-struct/contract`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/attaching-contracts-to-values.html#(form._((lib._racket%2Fcontract%2Fregion..rkt)._define-struct%2Fcontract))).
2. Define the struct with a guard, using [`struct`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define-struct.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._struct%29%29) with `#:guard`.

   a) A guard that uses a contract with [`struct-guard/c`](https://plt.eecs.northwestern.edu/snapshots/current/doc/reference/attaching-contracts-to-values.html?q=struct-guard%2Fc#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fcontract%2Fbase..rkt%29._struct-guard%2Fc%29%29).

   b) A guard manually defined with `unless`, `boolean?`, `raise-argument-error`.
3. Write your program in [Typed Racket](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/index.html) instead of Racket, and use a type like `Boolean`.

### 1: Struct with a contract

You can use [`define-struct/contract`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/attaching-contracts-to-values.html#(form._((lib._racket%2Fcontract%2Fregion..rkt)._define-struct%2Fcontract))) like this:

```
(define-struct/contract mystruct ([val boolean?]))
```

Using it, correctly and incorrectly:

```
> (define xt (mystruct #true))
> (define xf (mystruct #false))
> (mystruct-val xt)
#true
> (mystruct-val xf)
#false
> (mystruct 3)
make-mystruct: contract violation
  expected: boolean?
  given: 3
  in: the 1st argument of
      (-> boolean? symbol? any)
  contract from: (struct mystruct)
  blaming: .../so-54901923.rkt
   (assuming the contract is correct)
```

### 2: Struct with a guard

You can use the `#:guard` keyword of [`struct`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define-struct.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._struct%29%29) like this:

```
(struct mystruct [val]
  #:guard <guard-procedure>)
```

The easiest way to define a guard-procedure is with a library function like [`struct-guard/c`](https://plt.eecs.northwestern.edu/snapshots/current/doc/reference/attaching-contracts-to-values.html?q=struct-guard%2Fc#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fcontract%2Fbase..rkt%29._struct-guard%2Fc%29%29) on the Racket HEAD snapshot (not in 7.2, to be released in the next version of Racket).

```
(struct mystruct [val]
  #:guard (struct-guard/c boolean?))
```

Using it, correctly and incorrectly:

```
> (define xt (mystruct #true))
> (define xf (mystruct #false))
> (mystruct-val xt)
#true
> (mystruct-val xf)
#false
> (mystruct 3)
mystruct: contract violation
  expected: boolean?
  given: 3
  in: boolean?
  contract from: 
      .../so-54901923.rkt
  blaming: .../so-54901923.rkt
   (assuming the contract is correct)
```

If something like [`struct-guard/c`](https://plt.eecs.northwestern.edu/snapshots/current/doc/reference/attaching-contracts-to-values.html?q=struct-guard%2Fc#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fcontract%2Fbase..rkt%29._struct-guard%2Fc%29%29) is unavailable to you, or if you need more power/control than [`struct-guard/c`](https://plt.eecs.northwestern.edu/snapshots/current/doc/reference/attaching-contracts-to-values.html?q=struct-guard%2Fc#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fcontract%2Fbase..rkt%29._struct-guard%2Fc%29%29) provides, you can define the guard-procedure manually. If the struct has *n* fields, the guard-procedure should take *n + 1* arguments, corresponding to the fields plus a struct name.

For example, for your `mystruct`, it should be a function that takes the value of the `val` field and a name:

```
(lambda (val name)
  ???)
```

A guard-procedure should return a multiple-value result using *n* values, corresponding to the fields.

```
(lambda (val name)
  (values val))
```

And it can run arbitrary checks on the values before passing them through:

```
(lambda (val name)
  (unless (boolean? val)
    (raise-argument-error name "boolean" val))
  (values val))
```

Putting it as the `#:guard`:

```
(struct mystruct [val]
  #:guard (lambda (val name)
            (unless (boolean? val)
              (raise-argument-error name "boolean" val))
            (values val)))
```

Using it:

```
> (define xt (mystruct #true))
> (define xf (mystruct #false))
> (mystruct-val xt)
#true
> (mystruct-val xf)
#false
> (mystruct 3)
mystruct: contract violation
  expected: boolean
  given: 3
```

### 3: Typed racket

You can use [`#lang typed/racket`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/index.html). Its [`struct`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/special-forms.html#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fprims..rkt%29._struct%29%29) form has a type to every field:

```
#lang typed/racket

(struct mystruct ([val : Boolean]))
```

Using it:

```
> (define xt (mystruct #true))
> (define xf (mystruct #false))
> (mystruct-val xt)
- : Boolean
#true
> (mystruct-val xf)
- : Boolean
#false
> (mystruct 3)
Type Checker: type mismatch
  expected: Boolean
  given: Positive-Byte in: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
#lang typed/racket

(struct point ([q : Boolean] [x : Real] [y : Real]))
```

[http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/quick.html#%28part.*.Using*.Typed_.Racket_from_the_.Racket_.R.E.P.L%29](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/quick.html#%28part._.Using_.Typed_.Racket_from_the_.Racket_.R.E.P.L%29)